# Having trouble taking an index of an array and making it an NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I get an array from a JSON and I parse it into an `NSMutableArray` (this part is correct and working). I now want to take that array and print the first object to a Label. Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *title = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:2];
arrayLabel          = [title objectForKey:@"label"];
NSLog(@"arrayLabel = %@", arrayLabel); // Returns correct 

//Here is where I need help

string = [arrayLabel objectAtIndex:1]; //I do not get the first label (App crashes)
NSLog(@"string = %@", string);
```

other things that I have already tried are as follows:

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayImage objectAtIndex:1]];
```

and

```
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayImage objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Any help is greatly appriciated!

EDIT: The app does not return a single value and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't match the structure of your JSON. In your comment on the deleted answer, you said you got an exception when sending `objectAtIndex:` to an `NSString`. In your case, `arrayLabel` isn't an array when you think it is.

If your JSON has an object, your code needs to treat it as an `NSDictionary`. Likewise for arrays and `NSArray` and strings and `NSString`.

Comment: Ok so there is something wrong with my JSON. I will look into that. But then why did my NSLog display all of the strings?

Comment: You thought you were logging an array, but you were actually logging a string. Logging a string still works.

Comment: so how would I add a bunch of strings to my array?

Comment: I managed to do it but your answer really helped me see what the problem was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to whatever else was going on, you repeatedly refer to "first" but use the index 1. In most C-based programming languages (and others, as well) the convention is that indexes into arrays are 0-based.  So, use index 0 to get the first element.